# ReactJS, tutorial from codecademy won't work

Tags: reactjs

There is a really simple tutorial from codecademy about pushing state by parents to child, and using this props to pick up this value by children. It's really simple, I understand it, but it doesn't work if I copy these two files on my localhost. So I'm confused now, tutorial is wrong, or something wring with my computer. So my question is: It should be working or not?

parent.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Child = require('./Child');

var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { name: 'Frarthur' };
  },

render: function () {
  return <Child name={this.state.name} />;
}
});

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

child.js:

```
var React = require('react');

var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <h1>Hey, my name is {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
})

module.exports = Child;
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

 <title></title>

 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
 <meta name="keywords" content="">

</head>

<body>

 <div id="app"></div>
 <div id="test"></div>

 <script>__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ =  parent.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__</script>
 <script src="bundle.js"></script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

In this case "doesn't work" mean I have "Hey, my name is" but I haven't "Frarthur" on the screen. So I don't have props value. I have no mistakes or warnings.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get any error messages in the browser console? You've to provide more information for people to solve your issue.

Comment: Can you show us the 'index.html'?

Comment: Ok, so I understand this code should work correctly and I the problem has to be somewhere else.